# On the existence of covers that are not $\gamma$-covers

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $(U_n)_{n\in\omega}$ an open cover of $X$. Let us recall that $(U_n)_{n\in\omega}$ is said to be a $\gamma$-cover if it satisfies
$$
\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\bigcap_{k\geq n} U_k = X,
$$
or, equivalently, if every point of $X$ belongs to all but finitely many members of $(U_n)_{n\in\omega}$.

I'd like to know under which conditions one may guarantee that $X$ has a countable open cover that

(1) has no finite subcover;

(2) is not a $\gamma$-cover.

Is there a characterization of spaces with such property?

Comment: What do you already know in the way of conditions which are necessary or sufficient? E.g. "$X$ is not countably compact" is an obvious necessary condition, and "$X$ is not countably compact but some nonempty closed subset of $X$ is countably compact" is an obvious sufficient condition. What else is known?

Comment: @bof: For $T_1$ spaces those are equivalent. It appears to me that a necessary and sufficient condition is that $X$ have an infinite closed discrete subset.

Comment: @Brian: I see how it's sufficient. But I still have no clue on how it should be necessary.

Comment: @AndréPorto: It’s necessary because $X$ cannot be countably compact.